# want to display selected item price in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My java script function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready (function(){
    $(".dropdown").change(function () {
      var name = $(".dropdown").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "@Url.Action("selectprice", "Stock")" + "?name=" + $(".dropdown").val(),
        data: name,
        success: function () { console.log("Good"); },
        error: function () { console.log("Errrr"); }
      });;
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is my controller to retrieve the price

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult selectprice(string name)
{
  PharmaDB db = new PharmaDB();
  ViewData["price"] = db.drugs.Where(d => d.DRUG_ID == name).ToString();
  return RedirectToAction("Edit");
}
```

now plz check is this correct or not,and how to display the retrive price in view

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page so `return RedirectToAction("Edit");` is pointless. You need to return something to the `success` function and fix the way you are passing your values to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `controller` code to this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult selectprice(string name)
{
  PharmaDB db = new PharmaDB();
  var price = db.drugs.Where(d => d.DRUG_ID == name).ToString();
  return Json(price, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And change your `ajax success function` to this

```
 success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
```

In `console` your selected price will be displayed.

Comment: That wont work on its own because there are other major error in OP's code.